# How to remove specific divs of HTML using CSS grid if the screen size is less than 1180px?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my code:

I would like to remove the dvs `grid-item-2`, `grid-item-4`, `grid-item-6` when the width of my screen is below `1180px`.

Is it possible to do this using CSS GRID only?
Or I would need to use media queries?

```css
body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 10rem);
    grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-item {
    background: black;
}

.grid-item-2 {
    background: red;
}

.grid-item-4 {
    background: green;
}

.grid-item-6 {
    background: blue;
}

.grid-item-8 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main id="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9">9</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Why do you *not* want to use media queries? Detecting screen size is what they are for.

Comment: Yes I understand . But there is a way to do this without media query?

Comment: With JS? Yes. Without JS? No, or at least not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you need;

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1180px) {
  .grid-item-2,
  .grid-item-4,
  .grid-item-6, {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).